# what does repo init do?

Tags: android, git

As per android docs

> Run repo init to bring down the latest version of Repo with all its
>   most recent bug fixes. You must specify a URL for the manifest, which
>   specifies where the various repositories included in the Android
>   source will be placed within your working directory. $ repo init -u
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

What does it mean by bring down the latest version of repo?
and if it brings down latest versions of the code how it is different from repo sync

Answer (score 0):

In git in general, repo init will start a brand new repo. Repo sync will sync an existing repo with the remote version.

Comment: so infact the line "Run repo init to bring down the latest version of repo" is incorrect ? as it is not downloading the actual repository

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with working with Git in Android, but I think they're assuming you want to clone the repo to a new folder. Check the following link, it explains it pretty well: http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html